# OpsHub VS Online Migration Service Error: Read Timed Out

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I'm running into an error using the migration utility after installing v1.0.1.006. I have previously used v1.0.1.001 to migrate a sandbox/test project with success. I attempted to use the .001 version to migrate the full project but ran into the Processing blocked problem. The recommendation was to update to the .006 version.

Now after running for 30-60 minutes, I get the following error:

```
com.opshub.eai.metadata.MetadataException: OpsHub-014371: Could not instantiate metadata implementation for xxx to xxx| TFS Source 1409181936489 ALM TFS 1409181936495, due to ; nested exception is: java.net.SocketTimeoutExeption: Read timed out.
```

Restarting the app appears to make the process resume, only to have the same error repeat after another 30-60 minutes. As a side-note, the Work Item never shows me a count like it did in version .001, it just says Running.

Comment: Can you please zip up and send us the log files from location <c or d>:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs and email them to ovsmu@opshub.com Please include a reference to this request in your email so we will provide proper resolution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection refused error is logged continuously on your instance. From the logs it looks like your background services are not running properly.
Have you installed anything on port 8989 or 9090. Port 9090 is service port for tfs/vso side communications, but as per the logs service is not running or not responding properly. Also from the utility ui logs we captured that background opshub server service also not working. 
Can you please make sure following things.

- "OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility" is configured as
  Manual service and not running before you start migration utility
  This service will be automatically started by migration utility, it
  will also spawn process of tfs proxy on 9090 port.
- Port 8989 and 9090 is free and no other processes are occupying it
  during migration utility execution.

Regards,
OpsHub Support